# Making a client side Websocket connection request to a Go HTTP endpoint that authenticates and upgrades request to WS

Tags: javascript, go, websocket, postman

The title is basically the question I have. I was developing my Go server, and added the gorilla/ws library to the endpoint http://qwerty:1234/api/ws to handle connection upgrade requests.

This endpoint has a middleware before it that validates the Auth header's bearer token.

While developing I could customize the WS connection request in Postman to include the Auth header. And it successfully connected to the WS endpoint.

I'm new to WS. And I tried to develop the client side WS connection, lo, you can't add headers.

Is there a workaround to do what I am trying? Or is there a way to emulate what Postman does? Is there a Javascript WS library that I can use to do what I am trying?

Server code

```
// Router
r.Route("/api", func(r chi.Router) {

    r.Group(func(r chi.Router) {
        r.Use(utils.AuthMiddleware)

        r.Get("/contacts", controller.GetContacts)
        r.Get("/ws", websocket.Handler)
        r.Get("/ws/clients", websocket.TestHandler)

// Socket connection upgrade
func Handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    userDetails := r.Context().Value("userDetails").(jwt.MapClaims) // Populated by middleware

    userId := int64(userDetails["UserId"].(float64))
    if _, userPresent := wsClientsById[userId]; userPresent {
        http.Error(w, "User already connected", http.StatusForbidden)
        return
    }

    conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Error establishing Websocket connection", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    conn.SetReadLimit(4096)
    wsClientsById[userId] = conn
    wsClientsByConn[conn] = userId

    go wsConnHandler(conn)
}
```

Comment: If the client application is running in the web browser, then the cookie header is the only request header that the application can control. Use cookies or query parameters in this scenario.

Comment: Cookies are what I was thinking of trying. Not having the ability to add basic headers to the upgrade http request is just stupid.

Comment: Web browsers limit the application in the interest of security, not out of stupidity.  The code in the question has data races on wsClientsByConn and wsClientsById.

Comment: How does adding a Auth token on the HTTP upgrade request harm security? The points put forward by one of the maintainers of Chrome's WS are mildy infuriating (https://github.com/whatwg/websockets/issues/16). Seems like you have to write your own auth spec over what is essentially HTTP itself.
Thanks for the heads up.